# How to get unchecked checkbox value in jquery without using hidden attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net, checkbox

If the checkbox is checked return value is:

```
/doCheckBox.asp?checkbox-1=true
```

if the checkbox is unchecked I'm not getting anything in response:

```
/doCheckBox.asp?
```

Is there any way to return unchecked checbox value widouth using hidden attribute ?

doCheckBox.asp

```
<%
Option Explicit
Response.Expires = 0

Dim cb1
cb1 = Request("checkbox-1")
Response.Write(cb1)
%>
```

checkBox.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).on("ready", function() {

    $('input').checkboxradio();
    $('button').button();

    $('#button').on('click', function(){

      var cb2 = $('#checkbox-2').prop('checked') ? true : false;
      var cb1 = $('#checkbox-1').prop('checked') ? true : false;
      var cb3 = $('#checkbox-3').prop('checked') ? true : false;
      var cb4 = $('#checkbox-4').prop('checked') ? true : false;
      var cb5 = $('#checkbox-5').prop('checked') ? true : false;

      alert(" " + cb1 + " " + cb2 + " " + cb3 + " " + cb4 + " " + cb5)

      submitForm();

    });

  });

  function submitForm() {

      $('#form1').attr('action', "doCheckBox.asp").submit( function(){
        var cb1 = $('#checkbox-1').prop('checked') ? true : false;
        $('#checkbox-1').val(cb1);

      });

    }

  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="widget">

    <h2>Checkbox</h2>
    <form id="form1" method="get">

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Hotel Ratings: </legend>
        <label for="checkbox-1">1 Star</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
        <label for="checkbox-2">2 Star</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
        <label for="checkbox-3">3 Star</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3">
        <label for="checkbox-4">4 Star</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4" id="checkbox-4">
        <label for="checkbox-5">5 Star</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-5" id="checkbox-5">

        <button id="button" type="submit" onClick="submitForm()">Open Dialog</button>

      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Normally you wouldn't need that, because the unchecked checkbox will not be sent to the backend, which should map to the default `false` value of a boolean.

Comment: I'm trying to return that false value to .asp file so I can populate it in the database.

Comment: That's what I am saying. If you don't pass the value from the UI to the backend, the boolean in the backend will remain in its default value, which is `false`.

Comment: I get you now, Thanks a mil.

Comment: If you *explicitly* need the value, then having it default on the back-end is of no use.  It depends on your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

When you post a form, only the enabled form elements are included in the post.   An unticked checkbox is counted as not enabled, so, as you have found, you do not get the value *explicitly* passed.

You get around this by adding a *hidden input* directly after the checkbox, eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox-1" value="false">
```

they must have the same `name` and they must appear in this order (checkbox then hidden input).

when the form is post'ed, if the checkbox is ticked it will take the first form element (the checkbox value (`true`)) and if it is not ticked, it will fall back to the hidden input and take that's value (`false`).